# Excel ignore duplicates and list unique values dynamically

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to remove duplicates from column A and list all uniques to Column B.
When more ID's added to column A it should process them automatically

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in B2 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))/(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))=0),1)),"")
```

[image]